# Automatically create set of libraries when a site is created using teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams, modern-team-site

Is there a way to create a set of libraries in SharePoint online, whenever a new site is created via teams? Like can we force it to use a site template so that all libraries and content types will be available in the new site

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to force users to use a team site template.